# I need help finding the url or ip-address to my Openshift MongoDB

Tags: android, mongodb, openshift

I have been searching around for a way to connect my Openshift application to my android application. The Mongo library requires a url but I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone help point me in the right direction to find my Openshift MongoDB url.

This is the only url I could find but it doesn't appear to work:
appname-company.rhcloud.com

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

[MongoDB connection parameters](https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mongodb.html) are available as environment variables on OpenShift servers. For example

> OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL

But your database isn't publicly accessible by default. You'll need at least [port forwarding](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift).

Answer (score 0):

did u try this command

```
rhc port-forward -a <your-app-name>
```

You will get the ip for your mongodb